# Wordpress SQL query help (list posts from specific category)

Tags: sql, wordpress

I want to list those posts from wp_posts whose term_id is 38 , but i have a problem , term_id is stored in different table which is wp_term_taxonomy and wp_pst is different table, how can i search the particular record from these two tables ?
If term_id inside wp_term_taxonomy is 38 then show the records from wp_posts...how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the WordPress function get_posts(): http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

So, for example: `get_posts("category=38");` will retrieve the 5 latest posts from that category.